# "ValueError: too many values to unpack" in Learn Python The Hard Way, Ex 13

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I am using a Macbook Pro, running OS X Yosemite 10.10.4, and was going through the exercises in Learn Python the Hard Way. I'm running these on iPython notebooks, and their config is as below:

> Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (x86_64)| (default, May 28 2015,
>   17:04:42)  [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]

On Ex13, listed on http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex13.html
I typed and/or copied the exact code on the site but got an error.

```
from sys import argv
script, first, second, third = argv
print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

On running the above code, the error message I receive is this:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 script, first, second, third = argv
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack

I tried running the code line by line, and found that the problem is when I'm assigning more than one value to argv. For example, the code below executes fully.

```
from sys import argv
script = argv
print "The script is called:", script
```

The output for the above code is:

> The script is called:
>   ['/Users/myusername/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/**main**.py',
>   '-f',
>   '/Users/myusername/.ipython/profile_default/security/kernel-261810c2-9f04-44d4-95f7-411e0db361ff.json',
>   '--profile-dir', '/Users/myusername/.ipython/profile_default']

What could be the possible reasons for this, and how could I go about rectifying it?

Update:
I tried running this via terminal as suggested, and this was the response I received.
[image]

Comment: You should invoke it from the command line, exactly the way they tell you to. Don't use ipython for this exercise.

Comment: Basically the issue is that you have 4 parameters but your script expects 3. Try putting a `print(len(argv))` before your tuple unpakcing and see what the results from that are. If that's anything other than 4 you will have problems. The second code snippet will print the entire `argv` regardless of the number of parameters and hence not be a problem.

Comment: Thank you, but is this a limitation of the ipython notebooks that the code will work via Terminal but not when using the notebooks?

Comment: Eh, it's just that you needed to pass the code arguments via the command line, and at least on my computer ipython tried to open the arguments I passed it as files, which caused it to error out :P

Comment: `Invoke` your script from terminal (not python terminal) , command line terminal. (and don't write your code there) , first save it as a script and then invoke that script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its as the error suggests - `ValueError: too many values to unpack` . There are too many values on the right side, but not enough names/variables on the left side to accept them all.

In your case , your `argv` has 5 elements , but you are trying to store them in 4 elements. I am guessing this is something related to ipython-notebook.

You should invoke your script from command line (terminal) (just as the exercise tells you to) -

```
python <file> <args>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just execute your script from terminal like below:

```
$> python ex13.py user_name
```